# How to fix `uninitialised constant 'ActiveRecord_Relation'` in Rails 5.1.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

### Problem at hand

I'm currently upgrading the Rails version in one of our projects from 5.0.7 to 5.1.7, but I can't seem to find an explanation as to why the previously working call `BusinessTypes::ActiveRecord_Relation` doesn't work anymore. This call is performed as part of a spec, in order to check if the controller properly initialises a view model with the correct arguments (and an `ActiveRecord::Relation` with the correct class).

### What I've tried

1. I've tried to check the source code / file using the rails console, but to no avail, because I didn't seem to find any source. I've tried following commands:

   - `show-source BusinessTypes::ActiveRecord_Relation`
   - `BusinessTypes::ActiveRecord_Relation.source_location`
2. I've tried searching the `ActiveRecord_Relation` subclass on Google and in the Rails repos (5.0-stable and 5.1-stable), but I didn't find anything, only the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class itself, which didn't really help with my problem.
3. I've checked also the changelog, but nothing made me think that it had an impact on this.

### Code insight

The tested method `BusinessTypes#index` looks like this:

```
def index
  @vm = BusinessTypes::Index.new(@business_types.all, current_user, address_confirmed: address_confirmed?)
end
```

The faulty spec looks like this:

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }

describe 'GET #index' do
  it 'initialises the view model with the correct arguments' do
    expect(BusinessTypes::Index).to receive(:new)
      .with(kind_of(BusinessType::ActiveRecord_Relation), user, address_confirmed: true)
    get :index
  end

  context 'user has not confirmed his address' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, address_confirmed_at: nil) }

    it 'initialises the view model with the correct arguments' do
      expect(BusinessTypes::Index).to receive(:new)
        .with(kind_of(BusinessType::ActiveRecord_Relation), user, address_confirmed: false)
      get :index
    end
  end
end
```

### Expected vs. actual result

#### Rails version 5.0.7

This test would pass because `kind_of(BusinessTypes::ActiveRecord_Relation)` would return an object `#<RSpec::Mocks::ArgumentMatchers::KindOf:0x00007fe52529ae20 @klass=BusinessType::ActiveRecord_Relation>` which coincides with the object the controller gets passed as an argument.

#### Rails version 5.1.7

I get the following error: `NameError: uninitialized constant BusinessTypes::ActiveRecord_Relation`

The only thing that has changed between the two cases is the Rails version. Have I overseen something? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `ActiveRecord_Relation` is defined as a private constant inside `BusinessType`. You can't reference it outside of `BusinessType`.

https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module:private_constant

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f40860800c231ecd1daef6cf6b5a8a8eda76478d/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L25

However you can reference it like this:

```
BusinessTypes.const_get("ActiveRecord_Relation")
```

But I wouldn't reference it in the tests that way. I think a better way is:

```
expect(BusinessTypes::Index).to receive(:new).with(kind_of(BusinessType.all.class), # ...
```

Comment: Thank you! The first option works just fine, but regarding the second one I have a question: How do I prevent `BusinessType.all` from returning an array instead of the class itself?

Comment: Never mind, after a little bit of digging I found out that I can call `.class` at the end. Thanks a lot again for your explanation!

Comment: You are right! I just forgot to add `.class` there. Thank you for noticing! I've fixed the answer.